# Different BSOD messages every time I turn on the computer

Tags: windows, bsod

Every time I turn on my computer I receive a different BSOD. I can't even give info about my computer because I haven't been able to stay on it long enough.

The following are the BSOD messages that I just received in the last hour.

- `IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`,
- `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA`,
- `BAD_POOL_HEADER`, and
- `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`

I has also started with Windows Error Recovery which I have done, but that was freezing on me or hasn't helped either.

I have also reset the computer to its original state. Now as soon as I turn it on, it goes to a BSOD almost immediately.

I know you need more info about computer, so if you can tell me what info it is you need, I will get it. I can tell you that it is a desktop.

Comment: Start with a memory test (memtestx86). Sounds like bad hardware if you can't even get into recovery console... memory is the easiest and most common to start with.

Comment: To add to what Kyle said I would also test the hard drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does sound like you have some bad hardware, and from the messages in the errors you posted, it looks like the memory could be the culprit.  If you have access to a USB drive, you can download [memtest86+](http://www.memtest.org/), install it on the USB and boot your computer from that to see if any of the memory errors out.  Another troubleshooting step you might take is to launch your PC in safe mode.  To do this, reboot the PC and once you start seeing the loading info (BIOS, not the Windows screen) start pressing F8 repeatedly until you get a boot menu (don't hold the key down or you'll get a keyboard error).  Select safe mode and let it boot.  If you still BSOD right away, you have some pretty low-level/hardware errors.  If it lets you in, then it may still be hardware, but will probably be an issue with a driver or another non-essential component of the computer (sound card, network, etc).

If you figure out that it is bad memory, you can try removing one or more of the memory boards to see if it will boot without them.  Most PCs today can boot with a single stick of memory, so if for example, you have 4 sticks in your PC, you could remove 3 and see if it boots.  If it doesn't, then that stick may be bad.  If it does boot, then that stick is good and it confirms that the memory was the problem.  Continue this will all 4 sticks until you have isolated the bad ones.  If it will not boot with any of them, then the problem is probably elsewhere.  You can do the same with expansion boards as well (like sound cards, network, etc).  Just carefully remove the board and set it aside, then try to boot the PC.  If it works, then that piece you removed was the offending hardware.  Don't try this with your video card unless your motherboard also has video (or you won't know if it worked!).

Unfortunately, I can't give much info about how to remove these components without knowing more about the computer, but you can find general info about how to do it on sites like [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/the-geek-blog/building-a-new-computer-part-2-putting-it-together/), or by googling info about your specific computer (once you find out what it is).

Good luck!