# Blue Screen of Death - From the deep levels of hell

Tags: bsod

I have the worst BSOD I have ever seen. The biggest problem here is that it's intermittent. The BSOD happens a couple times per day The system is totally fine in between. There is no specific event or task that triggers it, seems to be completely random. The error, driver, and parameters are different every time.

This has been going on for weeks. Here are the items tested so far:

```
Motherboard - swapped
Processor - swapped
Memory - new
Harddrive - new
All USB (except k/m) disabled.
OS reinstalled
Non-essential services disabled.
BSOD occurs in safe mode
Video card - swapped
All temp/fans working and within range
```

This is a Windows 7 machine - Intel chip, ASUS board.

Here are a few of the most recent BSOD logs:

```
==================================================
Dump File         : 092815-7300-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/28/2015 6:46:53 AM
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : fffff8a0`211f19f8
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff800`03fcd32c
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000002
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18933 (win7sp1_gdr.150715-0600)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\092815-7300-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 277,608
Dump File Time    : 9/28/2015 6:47:35 AM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 092815-7347-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/27/2015 9:56:14 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00041284
Parameter 2       : fffff880`0c64a001
Parameter 3       : 00000000`0000357f
Parameter 4       : fffff780`00001000
Caused By Driver  : atikmdag.sys
Caused By Address : atikmdag.sys+12d394
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\092815-7347-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 277,608
Dump File Time    : 9/28/2015 6:37:17 AM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 092715-7222-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/27/2015 9:52:32 PM
Bug Check String  : PFN_LIST_CORRUPT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000004e
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000099
Parameter 2       : 00000000`0031f53e
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`0031ee3e
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18933 (win7sp1_gdr.150715-0600)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\092715-7222-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 277,608
Dump File Time    : 9/27/2015 9:53:43 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 092715-7269-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/27/2015 9:51:12 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00041790
Parameter 2       : fffffa80`08fca8d0
Parameter 3       : 00000000`0000ffff
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18933 (win7sp1_gdr.150715-0600)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\092715-7269-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 277,608
Dump File Time    : 9/27/2015 9:52:22 PM
==================================================
==================================================
Dump File         : 092815-7300-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/28/2015 6:46:53 AM
Bug Check String  : PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
Bug Check Code    : 0x00000050
Parameter 1       : fffff8a0`211f19f8
Parameter 2       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 3       : fffff800`03fcd32c
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000002
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18933 (win7sp1_gdr.150715-0600)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\092815-7300-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 277,608
Dump File Time    : 9/28/2015 6:47:35 AM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 092815-7347-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/27/2015 9:56:14 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00041284
Parameter 2       : fffff880`0c64a001
Parameter 3       : 00000000`0000357f
Parameter 4       : fffff780`00001000
Caused By Driver  : atikmdag.sys
Caused By Address : atikmdag.sys+12d394
File Description  : 
Product Name      : 
Company           : 
File Version      : 
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\092815-7347-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 277,608
Dump File Time    : 9/28/2015 6:37:17 AM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 092715-7222-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/27/2015 9:52:32 PM
Bug Check String  : PFN_LIST_CORRUPT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000004e
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00000099
Parameter 2       : 00000000`0031f53e
Parameter 3       : 00000000`00000000
Parameter 4       : 00000000`0031ee3e
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18933 (win7sp1_gdr.150715-0600)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\092715-7222-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 277,608
Dump File Time    : 9/27/2015 9:53:43 PM
==================================================

==================================================
Dump File         : 092715-7269-01.dmp
Crash Time        : 9/27/2015 9:51:12 PM
Bug Check String  : MEMORY_MANAGEMENT
Bug Check Code    : 0x0000001a
Parameter 1       : 00000000`00041790
Parameter 2       : fffffa80`08fca8d0
Parameter 3       : 00000000`0000ffff
Parameter 4       : 00000000`00000000
Caused By Driver  : ntoskrnl.exe
Caused By Address : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
File Description  : NT Kernel & System
Product Name      : Microsoft® Windows® Operating System
Company           : Microsoft Corporation
File Version      : 6.1.7601.18933 (win7sp1_gdr.150715-0600)
Processor         : x64
Crash Address     : ntoskrnl.exe+735c0
Stack Address 1   : 
Stack Address 2   : 
Stack Address 3   : 
Computer Name     : 
Full Path         : C:\Windows\Minidump\092715-7269-01.dmp
Processors Count  : 8
Major Version     : 15
Minor Version     : 7601
Dump File Size    : 277,608
Dump File Time    : 9/27/2015 9:52:22 PM
==================================================
```

Changed per superuser question on how this differs from a general question about bsod's

Comment: Are you sure the power supply is stable ? That seems to be the only thing that isn't swapped. And you state the RAM is new. That doesn't mean it is guaranteed to be OK. Try memtest86+ to test that properly.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention the power supply is also new.

Ran the Memtest as well, nothing found.

Comment: @user129208 In that case it is a real mystery... Strong radio-transmitter nearby ? Heavy equipment that might case bursts of electro-magnetic interference ? Is the power-supply connected to a grounded wall-outlet ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different BSOD messages every time I turn on the computer](http://superuser.com/questions/437424/different-bsod-messages-every-time-i-turn-on-the-computer)

Comment: +5 for your title.

Comment: No radio transmitter.

Machine is powered through a UPS and fully grounded.

Comment: Are you installing the correct drivers for the graphics card? Some of your BSOD logs say the culprit is atikmdag.sys which is your graphics card. If it is an onboard graphics card then go to your motherboards manufacturer site and get the driver from there.

Comment: Did you reinstall the same programs and OS from the same sources?  Possibly a corrupt install of something that doesn't verify file integrity?

Answer (score 1):

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA, MEMORY_MANAGEMENT and PFN_LIST_CORRUPT are all most certainly RAM problems, new sticks can still be defective, it's actually quite common.

You can run MEMTEST, try removing all RAM sticks except 1 at a time to figure out which one (or more) is the culprit. Or simply request a replacement from the retailer.